# How do I add a module dependency in gradle.build

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea. I have a java gradle project with two modules ('main' and 'repo'). I add a dependency in the main module to the repo module, using the "Project Structure" menu. My project builds ok, but when I run a sonarqube task in my project, the module depencency has gone. Is there a way to add a dependency to a module in gradle, so it doesn't disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure your project only in IntelliJ your gradle configuration will not be change because it is an IntelliJ configuration only.

The "normal" way is: first you set your gradle configuration and then just open your project in IntelliJ. Everything will work automagically inside InTelliJ.

Here is the [documentation](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/#add_a_java_application_sub_project) explaining how to add a sub project in gradle.

Comment: Is "module" the same as "subproject"?

Comment: Exactly. For each gradle projects/subprojects, InteliJ create one module.